# while submitting form data synchronously from react ,i cannot console log the axios response

Tags: javascript

```
const submitForm= ()=>{
  const newItem={
    name,email,phone,address
  }

  Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/insert",newItem) .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors at all in the browser's development console?  When using your browser's development tools, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  When using the script debugger, is this code reached at all?

Comment: no there are no errors but when i console log with axios then the console shows empty but my node application runs fine showing the data (inserting formdata in mongodb)

Comment: So the `console.log` statement *is* successfully running, it's just logging an empty result?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, in the network tab, what is the actual response from the server?

Comment: how to do that ? is it from inspect on the network section?

Comment: is it because i did post method while sending data and could not console the data

Comment: Now would be a good time to begin familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  The network tab can be used to examine the AJAX requests and responses, the script debugger can be used to directly debug the code as it executes, etc.  Just *guessing* that it has anything to do with using POST is unlikely to be helpful, but *observing* the actual behavior of the system will be very helpful.

Comment: in my network section it says  status code:204 content not found  ? what should i do ? i am really in dilemma and stuck in this for a long time

Comment: If the response from the server has no content, and the `console.log` is logging an empty result, then it sounds like the code you're showing in the question is working exactly as it should.  You'll likely want to no longer assume that the rest of your code *must* be correct and expand your debugging approach to include that other code.  In this case you'll want to also debug your server-side code which you claim "runs fine".

Comment: app.post('/api/insert',(req,res)=>{
    const newItem= new Item(
        { 
            name:req.body.name,
            email:req.body.email,
            phone:req.body.phone,
            address:req.body.address
        });
    newItem.save().then(item =>{console.log(item)}).catch(err=>res.status(404).json("Error"+err));
})

Comment: so this is the code ... i dont know where to find the smelly code

Comment: Relevant code should be included in the question, not in comments where it's difficult to read.  As for the code itself... Where in that code are you returning any data to the client?  What do you expect `response` in your client-side code to contain and why?  Are you just asking how to return a response to the client in Node Express?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the whole thing async as its intended. It will be more clear and function as expected.

```
const submitForm = async () =>{
  const newItem={
    name,email,phone,address
  }

 let data = await Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/insert",newItem);
  console.log(data)
}
```